# How to create Linq extension that get two parameters?

Tags: c#, linq

I need to write linq extension that creates and returns data table from int array.

Here the logic that have to be used inside extension.

```
    private DataTable CreateDataTable(string colName, int[] items)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(int));
        foreach (int item in items)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(item);
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

How can I make extension that have two parameters columnName and int array?

Comment: I'm not sure of exactly what you want, but I guess something like `private static DataTable CreateDataTable(this IEnumerable<int> items, string colName)` ?

Comment: `public static DataTable CreateDataTable(this int[] items, string colNam)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
public static DataTable CreateDataTable(this IEnumerable<int> items, string colName)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add(colName, typeof(int));
    foreach (int item in items)
    {
        dt.Rows.Add(item);
    }
    return dt;
}
```

The method just needs to be wrapped in a static class, and the job is done!